# Config.locale is deprecated

Tags: android

```
val locale = Locale(country)
Locale.setDefault(locale) 
val config: Configuration = baseContext.resources.configuration
config.locale = locale //deprecated
```

I'm using above code and `config.locale` is deprecated.
How should I apply locale into config now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use instead

```
config.setLocale(locale)
```